# Center image on remaining space when scroll on ViewPager android

Tags: android, scroll, resize, android-viewpager, parallax

I saw beatport's app intro with viewpager, and what I want is to create that effect on scroll, for example, when changing to the next fragment, the background image of the fragment before adjust itself in the center of the remaining space.
Maybe I wasn't very specific, I'll be glad if you could take a look at beatport's app Intro for more understanding. The effect is called Parallax and I found this pieces of code, but I can´t implement my fragments, only the images.

Here is the code:

https://github.com/je4a/ParallaxViewPager/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/com/parallaxviewpager/sample